# Invalid EE Conditional when testing stash variable

Tags: stash, conditionals

In my stash partial, I have:

```
{!-- Custom Sidebar? --}
{if "{exp:stash:get name='custom_sidebar_text'}"}
  <section class="container">
    {if "{exp:stash:get name='custom_sidebar_title'}"}
      <h3>
        {exp:stash:get name='custom_sidebar_title'}
      </h3>
    {/if}
    {exp:stash:get name='custom_sidebar_text' random}
  </section>
{/if}
{!-- /Custom Sidebar --}
```

In my template I have this:

```
{embed="layouts/.landing_page"}
{exp:channel:entries}
  {exp:stash:set parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes"}
    {!-- Several other stash variables --}
    {stash:custom_sidebar_title}{custom_sidebar_title}{/stash:custom_sidebar_title}
    {stash:custom_sidebar_text}{custom_sidebar_text}{/stash:custom_sidebar_text}
  {/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I’m getting a warning saying:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: User Warning
>   Message: Invalid EE
>   Conditional Variable: {if "
>   A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>   Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/agarzola/git/wfgc/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
>   Filename: core/Common.php
>   Line Number: 412

If I remove the outermost conditional tags in the partial (`{if "{exp:stash:get name='custom_sidebar_text'}"}` and '{/if}'), the markup is rendered perfectly, with the stash variables parsed as expected.

**edited to add:** This only happens when the `custom_sidebar_text` field contains a link (generated via Wygwam in this case). Take away the link on the edit entry form, save the page, and the error goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the hyperlink in your stashed variable likely contains double quotes, which is also the delimiter you're using to contain the conditional. So you're basically saying:

```
{if "<p>Here is my test <a href="http://url.com">with a link</a>.</p>"}
```

As you can see, this will lead to problems due to unescaped quotes.

Instead, use `:not_empty` ([docs](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3astash%3anot_empty%7D)).

```
{if {exp:stash:not_empty name="custom_sidebar_text"}}
```

Comment: I don't think I would have EVER figured this out. Thanks!